# Почему тревога "не является ответом" не предназначена для неверных/неточных ответов?

Tags: поддержка, модерация, тревоги, удаление-ответов

Почему тревога "не является ответом" не предназначена для неверных/неточных ответов?
Например я пометил [вот этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1055872/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%b2-python/1055881#1055881), как "не является ответом" и получил:

> отклонённые - Не нужно использовать тревоги для неверных/неправильных ответов. Они не для этого нужны ^_^"

Если эта тревога не подходит, то что делать с неправильными ответами?

Comment: @Suvitruf  says Reinstate Monica Судя по всему (а именно по ^_^) отклонили тревогу вы. Пожалуйста объясните мне почему это неправильно :) ?

Comment: Никогда ещё Штирлиц не был так близок к провалу :D

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica В смысле это не вы отклонили?

Comment: Конечно же я ^_^

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Нужно понимать, что тревоги должны использоваться для крайних случаев или для случаев, когда без модератора не обойтись.

"Не является ответом" нужно использовать для ответов уж совсем не по теме или ответов, которые тянут лишь на комментарий/правку:

- Если участник что-то переспрашивает у автора вопроса. Такое зачастую от новых участников, т.к. они не могут комментарии оставлять.
- Ответы-ссылки.
- Вопрос, опубликованный как ответ.

Если ответ плохой/неправильный/неточный, или не решил проблему автора, то такой ответ флагать не нужно.

Обычно отношение к таким ответам показывают минусами.

Comment: И это одна из причин, почему вместо нормальной базы знаний получается чёрт знает что

Comment: @andreymal голосуйте "против", улучшайте базу самостоятельно. Это можно делать и без ромбовидных модераторов.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ дед, хватит некропостить (ಥ﹏ಥ)

Comment: От деда  слышу пока еще без слухового аппарата

Comment: Вот и знак "Некромант" прилетел, значит, дед был прав :)

Answer (score 6):

Несколько лет назад на MSE появился запрос на улучшение формулировки тревоги "not an answer": [Should the not-an-answer flag description be clarified?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141210/339911)

Запрос обработали за пару месяцев и формулировку улучшили. Однако перевод на ruSO был сделан почему-то без учёта нюансов, поднятых в запросе.

Текст тревоги выглядел так:

> Сообщение было опубликовано в качестве ответа, но оно не содержит ответа на вопрос. Сообщение может быть правкой, комментарием, другим вопросом, но, возможно, его стоит просто удалить.

В такой формулировке это вполне можно воспринять как "сообщение не решает проблему", "ответ ошибочен" и т.п. Т.е. требуется анализ и проверка сообщения на соответствие вопросу, по сути, погружение в проблематику автора, задавшего вопрос. Необходимо обладать экспертными знаниями, чтобы можно было придти к такому выводу.

Поэтому недавно я подкорректировал [перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/9247) в соответствии с оригинальной идеей тревоги и теперь он будет выглядеть так:

> Сообщение было опубликовано как ответ, но в нём не содержится даже попытки ответить на вопрос. Это может быть правкой, комментарием, другим вопросом или его вовсе следует удалить.

Надеюсь, что это улучшит ситуацию: тревогу "не является ответом" будут реже использовать для "ошибочных ответов" и следовательно модераторам реже придётся её отклонять как неподходящую и нервировать участников, которые несомненно хотят сделать сайт лучше и убрать мусорные ответы. Но делать это всё же лучше не прибегая к услугам модераторов, голосуйте "против" или даже "удалить", если по вашему экспертному мнению ответ плох и недостоин быть позитивно оценён.