# Не стоит ли переработать список причин для удаления некачественных ответов?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Частенько проверяю ответы низкого качества и постоянно, выбирая причину, вижу список, в основном, из тех, что ни разу не использовал. При этом так же часто не нахожу там причин, которые хотелось бы указать на большинстве ответов.

Подробнее. При нажатии кнопки "Рекомендовать удаление" ответа появляется список из следующих причин удаления, выбрав одну из которых, я могу дать понять автору, что он сделал не так. Вот этот список с моими комментариями:

1. **Комментарий не требуются**. Во-первых, странно удалять без комментариев, но, возможно, с этим всё нормально, судить не возьмусь. Но то, что "Комментарий" в единственном числе, а "не требуЮтся" во множественном, – явная ошибка.
2. **Это не ответ, а комментарий к другому сообщению “В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша репутация достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению; на данный момент, пожалуйста, внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора.”**. К сожалению, большинство ответов приходится удалять по этой причине за неимением лучших. Хотя, на деле очень редко встречал ответ, который действительно выглядел бы как комментарий.
3. **Это комментарий типа «Спасибо» “Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Когда ваша репутация достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете проголосовать за вопросы и ответы, которые сочтёте полезными.”**. Возможно, у меня просто опыта маловато, но, если я за свои 200 с лишним проверок не встретил ни единого ответа, где кто-то говорил бы "спасибо" вместо попытки ответить, то, не смотря на маленькую репрезентативность, это всё-таки что-то значит. Возможно, раньше это и была одна из наиболее частых причин, но, насколько я вижу, сейчас это не актуально.
4. **Это комментарий «У меня та же проблема» “Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у вас есть другие вопросы, вы можете задать их нажав кнопку «Задать вопрос». Дополнительно вы можете добавить вознаграждение, чтобы привлечь к вопросу больше внимания, когда ваша репутация достигнет достаточного уровня.”** – тоже ни разу не встретил похожего.
5. **Это другой вопрос, опубликованный как ответ “Если у вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его при помощи кнопки «Задать вопрос». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.”**. Такое было, но всего один раз.
6. **Это ответ-ссылка (но не спам) “Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.”**. Вот это вполне объективная причина, часто встречал.

Но это всё вступление, основанное на моём субъективном и не особо большом опыте. Вполне возможно, что все эти причины до сих пор актуальны и имеют место быть. А теперь к более важному – чего не хватает:

1. Очень часто ответ дают недостаточно развёрнуто, в виде пары строк кода или "попробуй вот это". Сюда подошло бы описание от варианта "Это не ответ, а комментарий к другому сообщению", но ТОЛЬКО ОПИСАНИЕ. Сама формулировка вообще не отражает сути. Если бы я дал недостаточно развёрнутый ответ, а его удалили бы с формулировкой "Это не ответ, а комментарий", моей реакцией был бы ступор и нелестные слова в сторону сообщества по типу "Я ведь отвечал на вопрос, с какой, блин, стати вы решили, что это комментарий!?". Совсем другое дело, если это звучало бы как **ответ сформулирован недостаточно подробно** или **Необходимо дать более развёрнутый ответ, привести пример** и т.п.
2. Этот пункт спорный, т.к. основан только на мнении проверяющего, но бывают явно **неверные ответы**. Например, только что я встретил на вопрос новичка "Что такое классы и зачем они нужны?" ответ "Это что-то наподобие разметки кода". Конечно, мнение каждого имеет место быть, но, насколько я понимаю, проверяющие считаются более опытными и, тем более, даже если мнение проверяющего неверно, это всего лишь голос за удаление, а не немедленное удаление. Так что, думаю, стоило бы дать проверяющим возможность отсеивать подобное.
3. Бывают ответы, несущие в себе **опасный код** наподобие `sudo rm -rf /`. Думаю, это тоже стоило бы добавить в причины.
4. **Свой вариант**. В любом случае может попасться ответ, причина для удаления которого, несомненно, есть, но не укладывается в рамки ни существующих, ни предложенных мной вариантов. Для этого стоило бы внести возможность для проверяющего самому разъяснить, что не так с ответом, и как можно его улучшить. В идеале, этот вариант мог бы заменить вариант "Комментарий не требуется", удаление с которым, по моему опыту, вызывает лишь волну гнева в адрес SO и мемы по типу "Да чтоб я ещё раз что-то написал на этом сайте... Никогда!", тогда как подробное разъяснение от проверяющего причин удаления помогло бы улучшить сообщество и стать стимулом для новичков писать ответы более правильно.

Хотелось бы услышать мнение сообщества по поводу моих предложений и, возможно, другие предложения по переработке списка причин удаления ответов.

Comment: `Если уж есть вариант "Это ответ-ссылка (но не спам)", то где вариант Это-таки спам?` - для этого есть тревоги. Насколько я помню, для удаления по тревоге "спам" нужно меньше голосов, чем для удаления через очередь проверок.

Comment: Хотя возможно стоит дописать в этой причине закрытия, что для спама нужно использовать тревогу

Answer (score 8):

Если нужно руководство по проверке «неответов» можете почитать: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). В конце статьи дается картинка, которая иллюстрирует в каких случаях ответы надо удалять:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Just remember: if the text of the post contains an honest attempt at answering the question, then it is an answer - so don't flag it otherwise, and if you do, don't complain if your flag gets declined.

Т.е. модератор Meta.SO явно говорит, что если автор искренне попытался ответить на вопрос, то ответ не нужно отмечать тревогой и удалять. Если ответ неправильный, то при проверке такие ответы нужно отмечать «Выглядит нормально» и, если уж очень хочется, переходить на страницу вопроса и там минусовать.

Очередь создана не для определения правильности ответов. У проверяющего во многих случаях нет ни времени ни навыков для того чтобы определить является ли ответ правильным. Единственное что можно определить: может ли данный текст формально быть ответом.

### По пунктам

> **Комментарий не требуются.** Во-первых, странно удалять без комментариев, но, возможно, с этим всё нормально, судить не возьмусь.

Обычно этот пункт используется когда уже есть комментарий с объяснением, либо если ответ настолько безнадежно плох, что и объяснять не нужно (бессмысленный набор букв, например), либо когда ни один из стандартных комментариев не подошел и участник сам добавил комментарий к ответу.

> Но то, что "Комментарий" в единственном числе, а "не требуЮтся" во множественном, – явная ошибка.

Да, надо поправить.

> **Это не ответ, а комментарий к другому сообщению** ... К сожалению, большинство ответов приходится удалять по этой причине за неимением лучших. Хотя, на деле очень редко встречал ответ, который действительно выглядел бы как комментарий.

Странно. Приходилось видеть ответы-комментарии. Вот, например:

[image: Комментарий вместо ответа]

Ответа нет, вместо него уточнение у автора вопроса. Такое часто бывает когда участник еще не может оставлять комментарии.

Можете привести примеры ответов, которые Вы удалили за неимением лучшей формулировки? Так будет понятнее что имеется ввиду.

> **Это комментарий типа «Спасибо»** ... Возможно, раньше это и была одна из наиболее частых причин, но, насколько я вижу, сейчас это не актуально.
> **Это комментарий «У меня та же проблема»** ... тоже ни разу не встретил похожего.
> **Это другой вопрос, опубликованный как ответ** ... Такое было, но всего один раз.

Не могу согласится. Такие случаи встречаются нередко и очень хорошо что есть очень точная готовая формулировка.

[image: Спасибо вместо ответа]
[image: Та же проблема вместо ответа]
[image: Другой вопрос вместо ответа]

> Очень часто ответ дают недостаточно развёрнуто, в виде пары строк кода или "попробуй вот это". ... Совсем другое дело, если это звучало бы как ответ **сформулирован недостаточно подробно** или **Необходимо дать более развёрнутый ответ**, привести пример и т.п.

Ответ вида: «почитай документацию <ссылка>», действительно достоин удаления/преобразования в комментарий. Но если в ответе есть попытка решения, даже пара строк кода, то ответ не нужно удалять. Такой ответ может помочь спрашивающему, дополнен по необходимости автором и другими участниками. Ставьте минусы и оставляйте комментарии.

> Этот пункт спорный, т.к. основан только на мнении проверяющего, но бывают явно **неверные ответы.**

Это нормально. На Stack Overflow постоянно дают неверные/неточные ответы. Участники сами в этом разберутся, без инструментов модерации. С определенной точки зрения заминусованный неправильный ответ с комментариями лучше чем удаленный, т.к. он четко показывает что не нужно делать. В крайнем случае в ответ можно внести правку, объясняющую почему так делать нельзя.

> ... проверяющие считаются более опытными ...

У проверяющих большой опыт по использованию Stack Overflow, а не по программированию. Тем более что проверяющие часто проверяют ответы за гранью своей компетенции.

> ... это всего лишь голос за удаление, а не немедленное удаление.

То что на сайте будет висеть заминусованный неправильный ответ, само по себе не страшно совсем. А вот если правильный удалят, то на мете может развернуться цирк-шапито с истерикой и копрожонглерами.

> Бывают ответы, несущие в себе опасный код наподобие sudo rm -rf /. Думаю, это тоже стоило бы добавить в причины.

Если такие ответы будут появляться часто, то почему бы и нет. Но, имхо, лучше ставить тревогу и обращать внимание модераторов. Так ответ будет удален быстрее, а участника возьмут на заметку.

> Свой вариант. ...

Вот как раз для этого варианта, в очереди доступна кнопка «Добавить комментарий» и опция «Комментарий не требуется».

> Хотелось бы услышать мнение сообщества по поводу моих предложений и, возможно, другие предложения по переработке списка причин удаления ответов.

Предложения как предложения, что-то хорошо, что-то не очень. Плохо, что в одном вопросе этих предложений с десяток. Это мешает нормальному обсуждению. Лучше давать их по отдельности: один вопрос на правку орфографии, по одному на каждую «ненужную» опцию, по одному на каждую новую. Так от предложений будет больше толка.

Answer (score 5):

Я много проверяю и поэтому считаю, что мое мнение тоже может пригодиться. Вот мои проверки.:

- Первые сообщения: [history](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/history) | [stats](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats)
- Вопросы на переоткрытие: [history](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/history) | [stats](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/stats)
- Предлагаемые правки: [history](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history) | [stats](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats)
- Вопросы на закрытие: [history](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/history) | [stats](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats)
- Сообщения низкого качества: [history](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history) | [stats](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats)

## Сначала по поводу старых причин:

1. **Комментарий не требуются**.

   > Во-первых, странно удалять без комментариев, но, возможно, с этим всё нормально, судить не возьмусь. Но то, что "Комментарий" в единственном числе, а "не требуЮтся" во множественном, – явная ошибка.

   — правы, я и не замечал. Впрочем это редко нужная причина.
2. **Это не ответ, а комментарий к другому сообщению “В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша репутация достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению; на данный момент, пожалуйста, внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора.”**.

   > К сожалению, большинство ответов приходится удалять по этой причине за неимением лучших. Хотя, на деле очень редко встречал ответ, который действительно выглядел бы как комментарий.

   — мало проверяли. Хотя иногда ее используют для других плохих ответов. Но впрочем она очень часто полезна — за мои
   3,533 + 1,952 (закрытие и низкое качество) я ее много использовал.
3. **Это комментарий типа «Спасибо» “Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Когда ваша репутация достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете проголосовать за вопросы и ответы, которые сочтёте полезными.”**.

   > Возможно, у меня просто опыта маловато, но, если я за свои 200 с лишним проверок не встретил ни единого ответа, где кто-то говорил бы "спасибо" вместо попытки ответить, то, не смотря на маленькую репрезентативность, это всё-таки что-то значит. Возможно, раньше это и была одна из наиболее частых причин, но, насколько я вижу, сейчас это не актуально.

   — я встречал довольно много. Будет много проверок, поймете, что вполне актуальна.
4. **Это комментарий «У меня та же проблема» “Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у вас есть другие вопросы, вы можете задать их нажав кнопку «Задать вопрос». Дополнительно вы можете добавить вознаграждение, чтобы привлечь к вопросу больше внимания, когда ваша репутация достигнет достаточного уровня.”**

   > тоже ни разу не встретил похожего.

   — я встречал. Их примерно столько же, сколько "спасибо"
5. **Это другой вопрос, опубликованный как ответ “Если у вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его при помощи кнопки «Задать вопрос». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.”**.

   > Такое было, но всего один раз.

   — Редкое дело. Но бывает. Не надо убирать.
6. **Это ответ-ссылка (но не спам) “Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.”**.

   > Вот это вполне объективная причина, часто встречал.

   — Ну это классика. Есть даже высоко реповые участники, которые так отвечают.

## Теперь по поводу ваших идей

1. > Очень часто ответ дают недостаточно развёрнуто, в виде пары строк кода или "попробуй вот это". Сюда подошло бы описание от варианта "Это не ответ, а комментарий к другому сообщению", но ТОЛЬКО ОПИСАНИЕ. Сама формулировка вообще не отражает сути. Если бы я дал недостаточно развёрнутый ответ, а его удалили бы с формулировкой "Это не ответ, а комментарий", моей реакцией был бы ступор и нелестные слова в сторону сообщества по типу "Я ведь отвечал на вопрос, с какой, блин, стати вы решили, что это комментарий!?". Совсем другое дело, если это звучало бы как **ответ сформулирован недостаточно подробно** или **Необходимо дать более развёрнутый ответ, привести пример** и т.п.

— **Это  *нормальные* ответы! Оставьте их в покое. Не каждый ответ должен быть как война и мир или этот.**

2. > Этот пункт спорный, т.к. основан только на мнении проверяющего, но бывают явно **неверные ответы**. Например, только что я встретил на вопрос новичка "Что такое классы и зачем они нужны?" ответ "Это что-то наподобие разметки кода". Конечно, мнение каждого имеет место быть, но, насколько я понимаю, проверяющие считаются более опытными и, тем более, даже если мнение проверяющего неверно, это всего лишь голос за удаление, а не немедленное удаление. Так что, думаю, стоило бы дать проверяющим возможность отсеивать подобное.

   — неверные ответы удалять не надо — только минусовать. [Proof](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9971/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5)
3. > Бывают ответы, несущие в себе **опасный код** наподобие `sudo rm -rf /`. Думаю, это тоже стоило бы добавить в причины.

   — Обеими руками ***ЗА***! Это важно, эти ответы надо удалять.
4. > **Свой вариант**. В любом случае может попасться ответ, причина для удаления которого, несомненно, есть, но не укладывается в рамки ни существующих, ни предложенных мной вариантов. Для этого стоило бы внести возможность для проверяющего самому разъяснить, что не так с ответом, и как можно его улучшить. В идеале, этот вариант мог бы заменить вариант "Комментарий не требуется", удаление с которым, по моему опыту, вызывает лишь волну гнева в адрес SO и мемы по типу "Да чтоб я ещё раз что-то написал на этом сайте... Никогда!", тогда как подробное разъяснение от проверяющего причин удаления помогло бы улучшить сообщество и стать стимулом для новичков писать ответы более правильно.

   — Xорошая идея. И в духе StackOverflow.

## ...Что бы сделал я:

- Не ответ, а коммент.
- Ответ типа спасибо.
- Другой вопрос, а не ответ.
- Ссылка.
- Опасный код/совет
- Спам & rude. // Почему этого нет? Приходится открывать и флагать.
- Что-то другое. // кастомная тревога.

... все это переделать на о256ициальный стиль, но мне лень ;)

Comment: Почему же неверные ответы удалять не надо, если это поощряет система СО? Есть достижения, людям возвращается репа и в принципе у тебя в профиле не будет висеть ответ с рейтом -10.