# Насколько часто встречается практика удаления ответа без обоснования своих действий?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, часто ли встречается практика в русскоязычном сообществе: когда человек с кнопкой ставит на голосование удаление корректного ответа без обоснования и мнения автора вопроса?

Интересует именно субъективная  общая частота применения по сообществу, например:

1. Да, это часто практикуется.
2. Нет, такое бывает редко.

Спасибо!

[image: скриншот]

[Ссылка на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1140802/ruby-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5/1175088)

Comment: "без обоснования" -- но там же есть комментарий с обоснованием

Comment: Это попытка назначить класс/тип ответу, а не обоснование. Сам по себе класс/тип никак не обосновывает действия. Например, я пишу «ответ "полосатый"» — это попытка классификации. А если пишу «ваш ответ не несет смысловой нагрузки и не отвечает на вопрос, он "полосатый"» — это обоснование. Проще говоря, обоснование: это раскрытие мотива, побудившего совершить действие, а не само действие.

Comment: Это просто копипаста из очереди проверок, кастомной причины удаления там нет, насколько я знаю. Я согласен, что её часто неправильно используют. Например, когда ответ содержит ошибки, но ответом от этого он быть не перестаёт; или ответ слишком короткий, но при этом является ответом (думаю, ваш случай). Не знаю, в данном случае это так или нет, потому что не знаю Ruby. Думаю, что если бы вы привели пример кода, а не просто словесный ответ, то не удалили бы

Comment: @SergeyFedorov, я думаю в данном случае удалено ошибочно. Но вообще имеет смысл переформулировать ответ в более "утвердительной" форме, и более формально (без "запихать", "убить" и т.д.)

Comment: Возможно, вы правы, но выбор формы ответа остается за отвечающим и никакой модератор не вправе поставить его на удаление если ответ проходит по формальным признакам. Автор вопроса задал его на некотором уровне абстракции, без конкретного кода, поэтому я посчитал, что его интересует не реализация, а принципиальная возможность реализации. Что при этом подумал модератор меня интересует меньше всего, тем не менее я сделал попытку указать на ошибочность его действий.

Comment: Форма ответа имеет значение, т.к. stackoverflow - база знаний, а не чат или какой-нибудь паблик. Качество наполнения базы знаний имеет значение. В комментариях можно писать как угодно (почти), в ответах лучше писать максимально формально. Если ответ по форме больше похож на комментарий, его скорее всего сочтут комментарием и проголосуют за его удаление. Причем для удаления нужно 5 голосов обычных участников (не модераторов), и если 5 участников коллегиально посчитали сообщение не ответом, значит с вашим ответом все-таки что-то не так.

Comment: @dIm0n кастомная причина там **есть**, это же простой комментарий, который можно написать самостоятельно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov это понятно. Имелось в виду, что нет кастомной причины закрытия/удаления с произвольным инпутом. Это писалось как аргумент к "комментирующий участник не сам придумал такое обоснование, а просто скопировал готовое"

Comment: @dIm0n ЕМНИП, там "произвольный инпут" появляется прямо на странице проверки, при нажатии на ссылку "добавить комментарий"

Comment: @PavelMayorov [Вот как раз для этого варианта, в очереди доступна кнопка «Добавить комментарий» и опция «Комментарий не требуется».](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10687/398802) -- да, такая есть, вы правы

Comment: _никакой модератор не вправе поставить его на удаление_, какие отвеы попадают в очередь на проверку, определяет автоматика сайта. Сайт модерируется в основном самими участниками, и в вашем случае, шесть участников проголосовало за удаление. Давать ответ на низкокачественный вопрос вообще не стоит, а если даёте, то дайте хороший ответ, а не по принципу - _каков вопрос, таков ответ_. В данный момент, вы можете скопировать текст вашего ответа и опубликовать его комментарием, если действительно считаете, что он может быть полезен автору вопроса.

Comment: Да да, я тот самый, что периодически нарывается на несогласие о закрытии ответа. Инструментарий таков, что ответ можно только удалить, а донести до его автора мысль о том, что необходимо данный текст оставлять в комментариях к вопросу, не всегда представляется возможным. Поэтому, если я вижу, что ваш ответ можно было бы разместить в комментариях, я жму "Удалить". Простите.

Comment: @insolor *Форма ответа имеет значение, т.к. stackoverflow - база знаний, а не чат или какой-нибудь паблик. Качество наполнения базы знаний имеет значение.* Золотые слова. Прибить бы где гвоздями. Особенно чувствуется на англоязычном SO. Причём всем категорически похрен, получит автор вопроса помощь или нет, а порой даже единственно правильный и реально решающий проблему ответ - удаляют по вот этому формальному параметру, но оставляют хрень, автору сто лет ненужную и вообще не по делу, зато правильно оформленную. Я тут не первый год - и до сих пор не могу привыкнуть к подобному отношению.

Comment: @Akina, понятно что в крайности не нужно впадать. Форма имеет значение, но не только она.

Comment: @insolor У меня на фюзеляже на ихнем SO есть удалённый ответ, который автор ПРИНЯЛ. Правда, при этом пометка о принятии удалилась (хотя, может, и автор удалил - откуда мне знать) - но больше принятого ответа в той теме не появилось. Также там у меня есть принятый ответ, который был преобразован в комментарий. Так что я бы сказал, что форма имеет решающее значение, а остальное - постольку-поскольку. Да, у нас оно мягче, но генеральная линия-то та же.

Comment: @Akina, что тут можно сказать, s\*it happens

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, такое встречается довольно редко, обычно я вижу противоположную ситуацию: к ответу проверяющие умудряются "накидать" 2-3 различных шаблонных обоснований удаления. Лично я такую ситуацию считаю ненормальной, но ничего лучше предложить тоже не могу - к каждому "достойному" удаления ответу комментарий не напишешь.

Конкретно в вашем случае обоснование есть, и на вашем же скриншоте оно видно: ответ написан не в форме ответа, это в лучшем случае комментарий-подсказка. Чтобы получился ответ, нужно:

1. сделать что-нибудь со стилем сообщения, чтобы оно выглядело именно как отдельное сообщение, а не как реплика в диалоге;
2. добавить пример кода (это не обязательное требование, но без него мне потребовалось 4 раза перечитать ваш ответ чтобы понять что именно вы там предлагаете сделать - а новичку будет ещё сложнее).

Answer (score 4):

Большое спасибо всем, кто участвовал!

Из этого треда я вынес для себя мысль, что русскоязычное сообщество представляет собой группу людей с различными взглядами на происходящие события, готовностью к диалогу без лишних эмоций, поучений и достаточным уровнем эмпатии, а не тесный междусобойчик вахтеров-императоров: «брат за брата». Это здорово, я очень рад, мои опасения были напрасны.

Comment: Да, тут много очень разных

Answer (score 2):

Я, как действующий модератор, такие ответы не удаляю, ну максимум могу преобразовать в комментарий. Удаление надо заслужить - либо откровенным хамством, либо копи-пейстом, либо откровенным неадекватом.

Comment: В форуме тотал командера удалил модератор вопрос, то что ищу. Обоснование -  такой вопрос уже был. Гугл ведет именно на эту ветку, а то что ответ есть в какой то другой ветке я так и не смог найти. Из-за этого модератора потерял кучу времени.