# Является ли комментарий ответом?

Tags: обсуждение, удаление-ответов

Имеется следующий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1247013/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-5x2-%D0%B2-2x5/1247078#1247078). После того, как я дал свой [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1247020/385867), ТС тоже написал свой [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1247078/385867) со следующим содержанием:

> что-то вроде этого?
>
> // код

То есть ТС использовал ответ как комментарий. Он написал в ответе то, что должен был написать в комментарии под моим ответом. Я попросил ТС-а не использовать ответы в качестве комментария:

> Да что-то вроде этого. Только не пишите комментарии как ответ. –
> Zhenyria 22 фев в 8:19

и отправил тревогу по причине "Не является ответом". Меня очень удивило то, что сегодня я обнаружил свою тревогу отклонённой:

> не является ответом – Zhenyria 22 фев в 8:19   отклонённые - не
> следует использовать сигнал тревоги, чтобы указать на неточность или
> неверность ответа

Но это был не неточный ответ! Это вообще был не ответ, а комментарий!

Прошу всё-таки разрешить данный вопрос. Надо либо удалить ответ ТС-а, либо отредактировать его, чтобы реально получился ответ. Будет очень хорошо, если отзовётся тот, кто отклонил мою тревогу - почему комментарий ТС-а был принят за ответ, хотя таковым не является?

Comment: Вопрос - "Как транспонировать матрицу", в ответе код, на первый взгляд похожий на транспонирование матрицы. Почему не ответ?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight в принципе можно считать это ответом. Хотя это представлено именно как комментарий (ТС не отвечает на свой вопрос, он делает предположение и спрашивает, верно ли это предположение. То, что его предположение действительно является верным ответом - вопрос второй).

Comment: Тут все просто. Если ответ не нравится, вы его минусуете (а если нравится, то плюсуете). Вот и вся механика

Comment: @avp так проблема скорее в том, следует ли вообще это как ответ рассматривать?

Comment: Если текст в поле ответа, то это ответ.

Comment: @avp ну нет, очень вряд ли всё так однозначно. Иначе зачем вообще существует причина тревоги "Не является ответом".

Comment: @Zhenyria https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9972/400096

Comment: @Zhenyria, Наверное чтобы привлечь внимание модераторов к недопустимому контенту, например, призывах к терроризму и т.п.

Comment: @Danis а если какая-то официальная документация? Suvitruf - Andrei Apanasik как-то не тянет на истину в последней инстанции.

Comment: @avp `Сообщение было опубликовано в качестве ответа, но оно не содержит ответа на вопрос. Сообщение может быть правкой, комментарием, другим вопросом, но, возможно, его стоит просто удалить.` - ну тут вообще не про терроризм речь очевидно. `Если текст в поле ответа, то это ответ.` - как видно из описания самой тревоги, это не так.

Comment: @Zhenyria, вы слишком серьезно относитесь к формальным правилам. Смотрите на вещи шире

Comment: @Zhenyria на момент написания ответа он является модератором. ссылка которая была в справке https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81392/865952

Comment: @avp я не про терроризм... Да, за призывы к теракту тоже эта тревога подходит, но мы сейчас не о терроризме говорим. Первоочерёдно она предназначена для: `Сообщение было опубликовано в качестве ответа, но оно не содержит ответа на вопрос. Сообщение может быть правкой, комментарием...`. Вот на это я хочу обратить внимание. Это - комментарий!

Comment: @Zhenyria, здесь сколько участников, столько и мнений о том что и как нужно делать. Смиритесь

Comment: @avp это хорошо. Вероятно, именно поэтому и существуют правила. И правило о том, что нельзя в ответах публиковать комментарии - нарушается.

Comment: @Zhenyria, см. мой комментарий об отношению к правилам выше

Comment: avp прав, тревогу "Не является ответом" следует применять более по сути сообщения, чем по форме. Если ответ сформулирован как предположение, но при этом содержит законченный код по теме вопроса, можно считать его ответом. Если хотите пример того, что действительно не является ответом, вот: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Z3K0.png

Comment: На протяжении ряда лет я тоже несколько раз использовал подобную тревогу. Каждый раз она была отклонена с такой же формулировкой: "Не следует использовать сигнал тревоги, ..." Модераторы мышей не ловят. Забейте. Идея сделать качественную базу знаний не вышла.

Comment: На мой взгляд, это не ответ, а уточнение: как вставить ответ @Zhenyria в исходную программу. С другой стороны, это ответ, потому что содержит работающий код, который транспонирует матрицу, но ориентироваться в нём сложнее, так как кода больше.

Answer (score 11):

По моему скромному мнению сообщение ТС всё же не должно считаться ответом, и модератору не следовало отклонять тревогу.

У вопроса есть принятый ответ (автор поставил галочку). То что опубликовано следом, по сути является наложением принятого ответа на код ТС из вопроса. Обычно на SO так не делают. Если ответ автору не достаточно понятен и он хочет уточнить некоторые детали, то пишется комментарий (под существующим ответом), а не задаётся новый вопрос (хоть и уточняющий текущий) в форме для ответа. К тому же в таком виде автор ответа не получит нотификации и по итогам сообщением может быть просто не замечено им. Функциональность комментариев (по сравнению с сообщениями) ограничена не просто так. На SO не поощряются продолжительные дискуссии в комментариях, а если вдруг эта дискуссия начинает использовать функционал ответов, то это совсем плохо. Выходящая из ряда ситуация, на которую внимание модератора должно быть направлено в первую очередь.

Тем не менее иногда ответы от самого ТС (или других участников) вполне могут и должны оставаться в ответах, даже если они основаны на другом смежном ответе. Но только лишь в том случае, когда они действительно привносят что-то новое, развивают мысль чуть шире и т.п. Здесь же "ответ" от ТС не привносит ничего нового, и был размещён так лишь потому что впихнуть простыню кода в комментарий не представляется возможным. Но это всё можно простить ТС по причине наличия ярлыка "Новый участник". Однако простить - вовсе не значит, что стоит оставлять ответ, который просто должен был быть комментарием.

Answer (score 10):

Это ответ. Он содержит код (может и неправильный, нe знаю) имеющий отношение к вопросу и делает попытку ответа на поставленный вопрос. Чисто формально это ответ.

Comment: "Он содержит код .. имеющий отношение к вопросу." - ну такое себе обоснование. Ответ он, потому что делает попытку ответа на поставленный вопрос. Другое дело, что ответ, вероятно плохой, неправильный и некачественный, но ответ же! )

Comment: @Kromster Вот думал как сформулировать, но сформулировал плохо. Спасибо.

Comment: Рад если удалось помочь ) Можно еще добавить, что даже если этот ответ был дан невольно, он же все равно ответ (по факту).

Comment: Я не думаю, что формально это ответ... Разве что с той точки зрения, что этот текст находится там, где должен находиться ответ. Ответ, это высказывание, которое направлено на то, чтобы дать информацию, требуемую в вопросе. А тут автор просто спрашивает. Спрашивает! Если вы меня спросите: "Как у тебя дела?", а я скажу: "А у меня нормально дела?", то это что, ответ что ли?

Comment: @Zhenyria как быть, если для комментирования не хватает репутации?

Comment: @br3t вот честно не знаю. Видимо, никак. Иначе зачем ограничивать участников в комментариях? Только для того, чтобы они не могли комментировать, вряд ли для того, чтобы они публиковали комментарии как ответы)